# What Asymptotic Densities May Imply about the Intersection of Sets

Tags: number-theory

I have questions about what the asymptotic densities of sets $A$ and $B$ may imply about $ A \cap B$.

Let  $N \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and define the asymptotic density of $N$ as:

$$d(N) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|N \cap \{1, 2, \ldots n\}|}{n}$$

My questions are the following:

Q1.  Does $d(A)=d(B)= 1$ always imply $A \cap B$ is non-empty ?

Q2  How, if at all, does the answer to Q1 change if $d(A)$ = 1 and $0<d(B)<1$ ?

I found plenty of references to "asymptotic density" but could not find anything that answered these particular questions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The two sets must intersect when $d(A) + d(B) > 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $A\cap B=\emptyset$.  Then for any fixed $n$, we can partition $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ in to those elements which occur only in $A$, those elements which occur only in $B$, and those which occur in neither; call the counts of these $a_n$, $b_n$, and $n-(a_n+b_n)$, respectively.

This tells us that
$$
\frac{a_n}{n}+\frac{b_n}{n}\leq1\text{ for all $n$};
$$
we also know that (under the assumption that the densities exist), we have
$$
\frac{a_n}{n}+\frac{b_n}{n}\rightarrow d(A)+d(B).
$$
Thus we would, necessarily, need to have $d(A)+d(B)\leq 1$.

So, if $d(A)=d(B)=1$, or if $d(A)=1$ and $0<d(B)<1$, then it is definitely true that $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$. Further, we get the more general result (as in Daniel Fischer's comment) that the two sets must intersect if $d(A)+d(B)>1$.

Comment: I have a somewhat related question. Informally, given a set of integers $A=\{x_1,...,x_{\left\vert{A}\right\vert}\}$,  under what conditions is $d\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\left\vert{A}\right\vert}\{nx_i;n \in \Bbb Z^+\}\right)$ defined and how is it determined? Any member of $A$ divisible by another is redundant (the rest are sometimes called "primitive"). More generally, I know that the "redundancy" (density of intersection) of the multiples of two numbers is determined by their gcd, but I don't know how this is applied to an entire set.

Comment: @JaycobColeman It's an interesting question; why not post it as such?

Comment: I think I will expand it to its own question. I thought you might have encountered it before. To clarify, I'm interested in the method one could use to determine lower bounds for the density of abundant and pseudoperfect numbers from the [primitive abundant](https://oeis.org/A091191) and [primitive pseudoperfect](https://oeis.org/A006036) numbers, since every multiple of an abundant/pseudoperfect is abundant/pseudoperfect respectively.